# ICS draw bitmaps scaled up when minsdk is higher than 3

Tags: android

There is an ImageView in my widget layout which I put a canvas generated bitmap on it.

Today I came across strange problem when testing in ICS.

If I define minsdk version anything higher than 3, the graphic bitmap (from drawable resource) which is drawn on canvas are scaled up.

When minsdk is less than or equal to 3 everything is OK. This is how it looks in ICS:

[image: normal]

this is how it looks if I set minsdk to 4 or higher. Look how the sun is scaled up.

[image]

There is also another interesting issue, if the minsdk is 3 or lower, all the Toast message get so small while the widget is on screen!!!

Answer (score 1):

To test if your app works/looks the same on multiple devices, you should simply run it in different emulators (which use SDK Level 4, 5, 6... accordingly) without changing the minSdk-property. Set the `target=` property of the `project.properties`-file to the highest installed SDK (e.g. `target=android-17`), which means that you are compiling the app agains the newest SDK version. Clean the project ("Project" --> "Clean" --> "OK"), then test it on different emulator versions and set the minSdkVersion property of the manifest to the lowest supported version. That way, you shouldn't see any weird issues during testing.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out the problem.